# docker-compose where can I get a detail log (info) about what happened

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to pull and set a container with an database (mysql) with the following command:

```
docker-compose up
```

But for some reason is failing to start the container is showing me this:

> some_db exited with code 0

But that doesn't give me any information of why that happened so I can fix it, so how can I see the details of that error?.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for how to find an error in your composition, you should change your process. With docker it is easy to fall into using all of the lovely tools to make things work seamlessly together, but this sounds like an individual container issue, *not* an issue with docker compse. You should try building an empty container with the baseimage you want then using `docker exec -it <somecontainername> sh` to go into it and run the commands you're trying to execute in your entrypoint manually to find the specific breakpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Try at least [`docker logs <exited_container_name/id>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) (or more recently: [`docker container logs <exited_container_name/id>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/))

That way, you can check if there was any error message.

An exited container means the main process stopped: you need to make sure that main process remains up in order for the container to *not* exit immediately.

Try also [`docker inspect <exited_container_name/id>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) (or, again, [`docker container inspect <exited_container_name/id>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_inspect/))
If you see for instance `"OOMKilled": true`, that would mean the container memory was exceeded. You can also look for the `"ExitCode"` for clues.

See more at "[Ten tips for debugging Docker containers](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/ten-tips-for-debugging-docker-containers-cde4da841a1d#.l2blcxo7v)" from Mark Betz.